# CURL,JSON and PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, http-post, transfer

I am working to connect with an API using curl and PHP

I have this CURL statement

```
curl -i --user api:YXBpOmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1 --data-binary @test.png https://api.blahblah.com/blah
```

where YXBpOmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1 is the api key and @test.png is the image file I need to transfer to the API for upload. What I don't get is how to write the curl for the link above

and I also have this Example Statement as given by the site for developers(looks a JSON)

```
POST /blah HTTP/1.1
Host: api.blahblah.com
Authorization: Basic YXBpOmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1
```

Till now, I have written this up,

```
$url = 'https://api.tinypng.com/shrink';
$image = 'bf4lwp2.png';
$key = 'YXBpOmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1';

$jsonscript = array( 
'Host' => 'api.tinypng.com',
'Authorization' => $key );

$json_string = json_encode($jsonscript);

$ch = curl_init($url);
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'api:'.$key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $image);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
```

Also, if my request is a success, I get this...

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: https://api.blahblah.com/blahblah.png
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "input": {
    "size": 87654
  },
  "output": {
    "size": 102020,
    "ratio": 0.236
  }
}
```

I know I have to use `file_get_contents()` to get all that, but I don't know what URL to put in that function.

Comment: file_get_contents can't do a POST by itself. it'll only do GET. You'll have to use cURL, or use a stream to pass to f_g_c

Comment: Obviously... I wrote it there at the end... "I don't know what URL to put(or what to pass) in that function(file_get_contents())"... Sry, if I sound rude... Its my project and m kind of having an headache(not really, but you know what I mean) for spending so much time on it... Can you help me with the curl statement? Where I am wrong??

Comment: CURLOPT_FILE is writing the received data out to a file. it's not how you upload a file. that's done via postfields, and a `@` prefix on the filename. e.g. `array('@file' => 'test.png')`

Comment: @Marc B So, you are saying that I should use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file)` where `$file = array('@file' => 'test.png');`

Comment: pretty much.... plus the api, which probably would go in CURLOPT_USERPW

Comment: i think this png/jpg/image compressor is better way2enjoy.com/compress-png as it allows 50 files in one chance. plugin is not recommended as it will always keep your server loaded with excess load. i agree that it will automate the process but when you can do same thing in 1 second through online without slowing down your website.if you know any better then kindly share link.i think for any article or anything we are working 50 images are more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from json first you can use json decode and than use  foreach loop to 
parse those data into variables